# Iterable<String> to Iterable<T>

Tags: java, generics, iterable

The overridden method wants to return `Iterable<T>` but inside the method I have `Iterable<String>`. How can I return `Iterable<T>` from `Iterable<String>` or even `Set<String>`?

Code:

```
@Override
public Iterable<T> getAll() {
   Set<String> set = getCache().keySet();
   Iterable<String> iter = set;
   return ?
}
```

Comment: Why even use generics if its always a String?

Comment: What do you want to return? Is it the `keySet` ? If so, your method return type should be `Iterable<String>`, but I suspect you're expected to return something else, which will be an `Iterable<T>`.

Comment: Yes, I am expected to return Iterable<T>, but I have a Set<String>. Is conversion possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer - you can't.  No conversion is possible.

The declaration `Iterable<T> getAll()` says that the method is expected to return an `Iterable` that delivers instances of `T` where `T` denotes the parameter type used when the enclosing generic type is instantiated.

If your code can only return an `Iterable<String>` then it will only meet the call site's type requirements when `T` is `String`.  If that is acceptable, then you may as well get rid of the generic type parameter `T`.